# A beginner's guide to non-symmetric random matrix theory

Tags: analysis, probability-theory, reference-request, random-matrices

I am trying to understand how one can approach the subject of non-symmetric random matrices. Although I am knowledgeable in the theory of symmetric random matrices, I do not have any idea how to explore the non-symmetric area. This I believe is the more challenging and interesting one.

Are the questions raised in the non-symmetric case similar to those raised in the symmetric case? Like finding limiting spectral distribution, distribution of largest singular value, etc.?

Can you give me a reference or some materials to start with?